# Auto music composer based on the sounds I make manually

Tags: music-composing

Machine learning is quite popular now a days. Hence I was wondering if there is any tool available which can automatically compose music on the basis of sounds I make from my mouth or some non-music instruments like patting on the table.

Comment: I found mobile drum applications. It is helpful in some cases.